# How to stop "make" from running "clean"?

Tags: make, makefile

Have a Makefile like this:

```
all: build

build:
        dot2tex -ftikz temporal_dag.dot --figonly > temporal_dag.tex
        latex notes && bibtex notes && latex notes && pdflatex notes

.PHONY: clean

clean:
        rm -v *.aux *.bbl *.blg *.dvi *.fdb_latexmk *.fls *.log *.out *.toc
```

But include clean like that seems to result in "make" failing. I think clean is running.

Comment: Could you please update your question with the exact command and output / errors you get ?

Comment: Did you indent the line with `rm -v` using a TAB (ok) or spaces (wrong) ?

Comment: @SorenA I don't get reproducible errors when I include clean which makes me think there is a race condition somewhere and the "rm" is running in the wrong order. I've tried to catch it running by printing in the logs but am still not sure what is going on yet.

Comment: And the errors are basically some variant of some of the files missing or something in the bibtex step going wrong.

Comment: One example is "I can't find file `notes.aux'". Then the next run produces: ") [4] (./notes.aux
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.". Then the next run finishes successfully!

Comment: In the build constructions I see `latex notes` twice. Which program makes the `notes.aux`, can this be done before the `build` step (target `build` depending on target `helpfiles`, and target `helpfiles` generating `notes.aux`) ?

Comment: I've added a sleep .1 in between commands and am not hitting the issue anymore. Seems like a race condition in the latex commands. Can't think of anything else that would cause it.